# What open source Node.js CI project are there?

Tags: node.js, open-source, continuous-integration

What open source *continuous integration servers* written with Node.js do you know of? What are their features, pros and cons, your experience? Do they support continuous deployment ("deploy on green")?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strider is an Open Source Continuous Deployment / Continuous Integration platform. It is written in Node.JS / JavaScript and uses MongoDB as a backing store. It is published under the BSD license.

Strider is conceptually similar to Travis-CI or Jenkins with the following major differences:

- A focus on Continuous Deployment rather than just Continuous Integration
- Designed to be easy to install & setup
- Deployable & usable on Heroku free plan
- Intended for deployment on private infrastructure
- An emphasis on extensibility. Plugins are powerful, easy to write and simple to install.
- Out-of-the-box support for projects written in Node.JS, Python (generic and  Django/Pyramid) and Selenium/Sauce Labs tests
- Commercial support, consulting & hosting available

http://stridercd.com

Answer (score 1):

our team just started such project.

It's called pragma-ci and you can watch it on GitHub https://github.com/pragma-dudes/pragma-ci. We plan to release first stable version in the end of this month.

It is distributed system for continuous integration written in node.js using MongoDB.

It consist of:

- Build Service
- API Service
- Front-end web application written in AngularJS

Every component may be deployed in one or more instances. It's very similar to GitLab CI but written in node.js and has different Web UI.

First release will have following features:

- Git VCS support
- GitHub support with WebHook URL trigger and payload (you can add a service hook in your GitHub repository)
- npm support for dependency resolving and tests running
- Deployment to specified path with pre- and post-deployment scripts (only deploy to machine where build service was run but you can sync directories by some service anyway)

Stay tuned!

Comment: So did you guys decide to not continue with this? I see no checkins in a year?

Comment: Unfortunately, we stop all activities in pragma-dudes group and stop all projects.

Comment: Bummer my I ask why you stopped? Was there a better project? Not needed?

Comment: Seems that project was alive only for 14 days.