# ExpressJS as an Orchestration layer?

Tags: node.js, express

How would one use ExpressJS as an orchestration layer?

I have five NodeJS / ExpressJS "API applications" for different business functions (security, human resources, asset management, fleet management, etc.).  Each provides raw object / document APIs and has its own database, app server, routes, etc..  I would like to build ANOTHER ExpressJS application to sit IN FRONT OF those five "stacks" and provide higher-level business operations (ie, TerminateEmployee, etc.) by funneling multiple calls into the other five stacks via REST.

Am I insane?  Is this common?  Maybe I don't know what to search for, but I'm not finding any examples of doing this.

BTW: I'm also thinking of building highly-reusable "widgets" (basically, individual AngularJS services and UI elements) to call into that sixth front-end stack.

Comment: This seems like a pretty typical micro-service or bog-standard SOA. Not really sure what the question is.

Comment: Among enterprise users of node.js your orchestration layer is considered the sweet spot for node.js

Comment: Know of any good articles or examples of this?  I cannot find anything.  I might be searching for the wrong terms but "ExpressJS as an orchestration layer" yields nothing that resembles this.

Comment: Walmart, Paypal, Linkedin, intuit etc . . . all use node.js that way, I'm sure Eran Hammer of Walmart Labs has a good talk and/or article about the topic among others.

Comment: Because it's not called an "orchestration layer". It's SOA, and your "orchestration layer" is a service built on the other services (which may or may not be called micro-services depending on who you ask).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What open source Node.js CI project are there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523596/what-open-source-node-js-ci-project-are-there)

Answer (score 0):

Whoa, an old question left unanswered.

SOA, Microservice, or whatever the name is only the abstract thought of system architecture, they need to be applied, now let us define the problem

Problem: *need orchestration for middleware*

Parameter: *we need to define what middleware need to be run (maybe a String for service name and Number for service port) and this value need to be passed as CLI args or process.env*

First we need to store our parameter in JS readable format, could be an Array or Object, in my case i need to run multiple service at one port and the app need to be exposed in multiple port eg:

from String

```
graphql:80 auth:5000 usercrud:5000 trx:6969 docs:4000
```

to JSON

```
{
    "80":["graphql"],
    "5000":["auth", "usercrud"],
    "6969":["trx"],
    "7070":["ssr"],
    "4000":["docs"]
}
```

we can make CLI accept args by using the popular `yargs`, but also need to be able read from string passed from .env file, when parsing a string this is quite easy since we can control the format of the string by simply using `String.split()` function we can make an Array, i prefer using space when separating context (in this case a middleware/service) followed by `:` and port of this particular service, like `auth:5000` and then from this Array we can map the value to an Object (note `"5000":["auth", "usercrud"]` is sharing the same port so we need to accommodate this two service).

from this config we can iterate the keys which is reflected by its port, so doing `Object.keys(service)` return an Iterable/Array that we can Map/ForEach according to modern EcmaScript standard. In each iteration we make

```
app.use(require(`./service/${service[port]}`))
http.createServer(app)
    .listen(port, () => 
        log(`http://127.0.0.1:${port} >>> ${service[port]}`)
    )
```

usually when we `http.createServer(app)` we do this once, but now we do it as many as the port we need to exposed, this increased atomicity and decrease dependency inter services.

advantage of this approach is:

- can share library / helper
- single codebase & consistency
- single container development / staging / integration test
- controlled service based on resource consumption (not only task, if one of the service is idle / consuming very little resource we can join it with the other service)

up & running source: https://github.com/nsnull0/eService/blob/master/packages/%40nodejs-express/index.js